# Set default value of dropdown in multiple pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

In my application there is one master page and multiple content pages. Each page contains one dropdownlist with the id `drplstYear`. Now I want to set default value for each dropdownlist. I can set default value by writing code in each page. Any other solution like write code in master page and it will apply in all pages? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Are you using mvc, web-forms, or what?

Comment: There are quite a few solutions available to persist data across pages and req/res cycles, but this will depend on what you are using. The most universal way of achieving this is storing it in the Session object and retrieving it before page load, but better solutions might exist depending on what technology you are using. Please provide as much details as possible.